# Parse error when on production

Tags: symfony, filezilla, symfony-2.2

I have developed a Symfony2 project (v2.2.2) and it was working all fine locally.

When I deploy it on my server I meet 2 issues:

- the folder /bin does not transfer through Filezilla (impossible to start transfer)
- i encounter a parse error when trying to access web/app.php/ in debug mode (see below)

First I do not understand why it would work in local but not on production.
I also guessed these errors where linked but I do not know what is /bin used for (contains only 2 files doctrine and doctrine.php) and if I remove it locally it keeps working ...

Parse error is the following :

"FatalErrorException: Parse: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/colocall/twinkler/src/Tk/ExpenseBundle/Services/Expenses.php line 21"

Expenses.php line 15->25:

```
public function getAllExpenses($member, $group)

{
    $all_expenses_col = $group->getExpenses();
    $all_expenses = array();

    foreach($all_expenses_col as $expense){
        $all_expenses[] = [$expense, $this->forYou($member, $expense)];
    }

    return $all_expenses;
}
```

Maybe linked to : The parse error also happen when i try to update my database through ssh connection.

If someone would know the reason why I can't make it working it would save my day that i have already lost ...

Thank you in advance,
Jules

Comment: What php version are you using on both? And what code is in Expenses.php on line 21

Comment: Local php 5.4.4 / on my server php 5.3.10.
Expenses.php code added to the post, but this code is working locally...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is produced by using the short array syntax [] in your code.

It is not available in PHP 5.3.10 aka on your production server. The short syntax was introduced in PHP 5.4 which explains why your code is working in your dev-environment.

change ...

```
$all_expenses[] = [$expense, $this->forYou($member, $expense)];
```

...to

```
$all_expenses[] = array($expense, $this->forYou($member, $expense));
```

... or update your server's php version and it will work :)

Comment: array(value,value) or array(key => value, key => value) instead of [value, value] and [key => value, key => value]

Comment: ok thank you very i will update all my code then ... 
And is it a problem that my folder /bin cannot be transfered to my server ?

Comment: Funny I ran exactly in the same issue that's why I was wondering what his server version was :)